# Storing in a variable frame from webcam in Processing

Tags: processing, webcam

I've tried a lot of time to store in a variable a frame from the webcam, but it doesn't work. The goal is to compare two consecutive frames from the video, so I need to store two frames in two variables, but storing one is already harder that what I thought.. Here's the code that corresponds to this problem:

```java
import processing.video.*;

Capture video;
PImage image1;

void setup() {
  size(1280, 960);
  println("Caméras disponibles : ");
  printArray(Capture.list());
  video = new Capture(this, Capture.list()[75]);
  video.start();
}

void draw() {
  if (video.available() == true) {
    video.read();
    image1 = video;
  }

  image(image1, 0, 0);
}
```

It works fine when I write image(video, 0, 0); but as soon as I try to replace it by the variable image1, it doesn't print anything. Hence, the problem is the third line...

Would anyone have an idea of what is going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @PatrickArtner Processing is a language.

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] instead of a disconnected snippet? What happens in this code if `video` is not available? What will the value of `image1` be?

Comment: You just figured out my problem! Indeed, there wasn't anything because it was doing it even if there wasn't any video available... Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @MaloMaisonneuve Apologies. did not know processing is a lang

Comment: @KevinWorkman thanks for correcting me - should have read the processing tag instead of assuming it means "processsing" as in "processing video".

Comment: @MaloMaisonneuve Glad you got it figured out. I've expanded my comment into an answer. Note that using a `Capture` like this probably won't work, because its internal state always stores the latest frame. See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only set `image1` to a value if your `if` statement evaluates to true:

```java
  if (video.available() == true) {
    video.read();
    image1 = video;
  }

  image(image1, 0, 0);
```

So what happens if `video.isAvailable()` is `false`? You won't set `image1` equal to anything, so it retains its original value. Since it's original value is unset, it's the `null` value. Passing `null` into the `image()` function apparently doesn't draw anything.

To fix your problem, you need to refactor your code to only draw `image1` if it has a value. It could be as simple as this:

```java
  if (video.available() == true) {
    video.read();
    image1 = video;
    image(image1, 0, 0);
  }
```

This is just a guess, and what you do depends on how you want your code to behave.

But one thing to note is that `Capture` is a special instance of `PImage`, so I'm not sure that what you're trying to do will work. `Capture` instances modify their internal state so that drawing the same `Capture` over time will draw different frames. So if you set two `PImage` variables equal to the same `Capture`, those two variables will continue to update along with the video. They'll always store the most recent frame.

To fix that, you'll probably want to copy the current pixels from the `Capture` to each `PImage` variable.

Comment: It works definitely better by copying the pixels, thanks for your patience and time ;)